# SvelteKit store returns object in server console but is undefined in browser console

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

after logging my user in, I'm setting the `userSession` store. When printing that out right after it's being set, I get the stores' value printed in my server console. When trying to access the `userSession` store from within my component, I get the stores' value printed into my server console once again but in my browser console I simply get `undefined` and cannot access the stores' value.

login/+page.server.ts:

```
const user: User = {"username": "test", "email": "email@test.com"};
userSession.set(user);
// this prints user obj in server console
console.log("Backend " + JSON.stringify(get(userSession)))
```

lib/stores.ts:

```
export const userSession: Writable<User> = writable();
```

components/HeaderComponent.svelte:

```
$: {
    let user: User = $userSession;
    // this prints user obj in server console but browser console returns undefined
    console.log("Frontend " + JSON.stringify(user))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stores do not magically get transferred between server and client, you should not use them on the server anyway. There also would just be one instance for all users. (If you need server-side state you have to make sure to separate it by user/session.)

Load the data from the server e.g. via a [layout `load` function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#layout-data), that way all pages using said layout will have access via the `data` property.

Comment: thank you for your help! i'll do it like that